# Sass: Is there a way to watch files recursively?

Tags: node.js, sass, node-sass, node-sass-chokidar

I am new to Sass and I was updating dependencies of a NodeJS project in which it used Node-Sass and Node-Sass-Chokidar. I've switched it to Sass and while translating the old scripts to Sass it successfully compiled but I get the following output:

```
Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch 'some/path/some-file'
Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch 'some/path/some-file'
Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch 'some/path/some-file'
Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch 'some/path/some-file'
...
```

My new `build-css` and `watch-css` look like this:

```
"build-css": "sass --load-path=./src --load-path=./node_modules src:src",
"watch-css": "npm run build-css && sass --load-path=./src --load-path=./node_modules src:src --watch",
```

My old `build-css` and `watch-css` used to look like this:

```json
"build-css-old": "node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/",
"watch-css-old": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
```

Did I mess something up while translating them or is it because there's no `--recursive` option (as far as I know) in Sass?

The versions of `Sass` and `Node-Sass-Chokidar`:

```json
...
"node-sass-chokidar": "^1.5.0",
"sass": "^1.43.4",
...
```